# Do nanoscopes exist?

Tags: nanoscience, subatomic, microscopy, experimental-technology

We are mostly all familiar with a microscope, and know that it helps to see MICRO components, like stuff that is photolithographically etched on silicon semiconductor die.

(The latter can also be nano, but let's bide that.)

Anyways, we rarely hear of [nanoscopes](http://www.google.com/#q=nanoscope), i.e. a lens that can digitally reflect traces of nanometer objects, like quarks, hadrons, and valence electrons.

I want to purchase a good microscope, but that will only let me see cells, substrate micro-components, etc. I want to see the actual atoms that make up the silicon, the atoms that make up the doped logic gates in my tablet, the atoms that make up my arm, and the atoms in the air that surrounds our very demanding atmosphere of carbon dioxide!

So I ask again, with endless respect for science, do nanoscopes exist, and if they don't, how close can I get to the atoms, quarks, and hadrons, and how do I tell them all apart!

Answer (score 3):

A nanoscope in the sense you're talking about would be physically impossible, because things which are smaller than the wavelength of light don't reflect light. They do *scatter* light, but that's a different process which doesn't form a coherent image. Visible light has wavelengths between about 400 and 700 nanometers, so anything smaller than that - including atoms and small molecules - can never be directly seen.

What you *can* do, however, is use some other "probe" which has a much smaller wavelength instead of visible light. You will need a camera to capture the reflection, and a computer to convert it into a visible image, but this does let you get as close as is physically possible to "seeing" things smaller than a few hundred nanometers. For example, an [electron microscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_microscope) uses an electron beam with a wavelength on the order of 10 picometers (0.01nm), and can thus resolve objects down to that size, including atoms.

To achieve smaller resolutions, you need more powerful (and larger) devices, namely particle accelerators. The LHC acts somewhat like a microscope using a quark/gluon beam of wavelength around an attometer, roughly a thousandth the size of a proton. Of course, in that case the formation of an image is complicated by the fact that the probe destroys whatever you were trying to form an image of in the first place. ;-)

Comment: One should perhaps mention that electron microscopes and particle accelerators are not exactly priced for consumers.

Comment: Nor are they turn-key devices that can be operated with-out a degree of expertise (exect that I understand that some electron micro-scopes are getting to be that way, only they are even *more* expensive).

Comment: @dmckee You don't need a degree to know things. ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as resolution goes, right now the best in practice are [high resolution transmission electron microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-resolution_transmission_electron_microscopy) (which involves firing high energy electrons), high resolution [scanning force microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_force_microscopy) (which involves a very sharp tip vibrating above a surface), and the classic [scanning tunneling microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope) (which involves conduction through a very narrow vacuum gap between a tip and sample). All of these techniques have resolution at the atomic level and are truly nanoscopes with sub-nanometer resolution.

These techniques require special types of samples: very thin solid samples for transmission microscopy, or surface-exposed solid samples for scanning microscopy. None of them would be useful to image your silicon or your cells, unless you prepare a special cut. And none of them are fast enough to image air. Moreover these machines are expensive and very awkward to use without significant time investment in training.

Unfortunately, the scanning microscopes will not be able to reach resolutions smaller than the electron clouds of the atoms concerned, since they involve exclusively low energy electron physics. The transmission microscopes will likely only be able to achieve better resolutions by using higher energies, however the energies they are using now already severely damage the samples in question. So, what will be very amazing is if someone can come up with a very high resolution microscope that is non-damaging.

Fortunately, we are not missing out on very much. If we go much smaller then we will start to see core orbitals, however the structures of core orbitals have already been fairly well inferred. Perhaps we will get some very pretty pictures from our picoscopes, but even having a picture of the subatomic structure would be deceivingly simple. There is so much happening in the femtosecond dynamics and energetics that the microscope does not capture, with its slow acquisition time.

(Now, if you can get me a high spatial resolution, high time resolution, noninvasive microscope, that would be truly amazing. I would quite like to see a real movie of the H20 molecules dancing around in a drop of water.)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some simple comments to [David Z's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/87564/26076) and [Nanite's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/87578/26076) answers, particularly a quantification of David's last paragraph, and his last paragraph is not only to do with "destruction" of the sample with a high energy probe, but also with the stronger and stronger ["observer" effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28physics%29) that goes with the use of higher and higher energies.

Recall the equation for the squared "length" of the momentum four-vector (the general form of $E=m\,c^2$):

$$E^2 - p^2 \,c^2 = m^2\, c^4$$

so that, given the de Broglie wavelength of a probe particle of momentum $p$ is $h/p$:

$$E\geq h\,c\,\lambda^{-1}$$

Therefore, if we want to image of the order of picometres ($\lambda^{-1}=10^{12}$ "lines per metre" in microscopy jargon) you find that the energy of the probe particle approaches the electron's rest energy (550keV). So once we go much beyond the current resolution of electron microscopes, the resulting image is going to become very hard to interpret, because the energies involved can *create* new electrons and positrons through pair production, so forget about leaving the electron clouds of your probed atoms undisturbed! There can be spurious scattered electrons not present in the original beam! (The "observer effect" is not to be confused with the uncertainty principle, although the former includes the latter as a special case and as a lower limit to the former's effect. Also not to be confused with what is known humourously in German labs as the "vorführungseffekt" (demonstration effect): the wont of something you've poured your soul into setting up to break down in the presence of your boss, colleague or customer!)

A second notion worth raising is the idea of *optical superresolution* such as [stimulated emission depletion microscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STED_microscopy), [ground state depletion microscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSD_microscopy) and like ideas pioneered for example by [Stefan Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_Hell). This is often sensationally described as "breaking the diffraction limit of light" but this is misleading. The essential idea is that some further information is used to localise where a detected photon has come from and this further information is what gets one below the diffraction limit. For example, STED microscopy uses a high powered "fore-pulse" focussed as a first order (one with a null at its centre and whose intensity varies like $r^2 e^{-\alpha\,r}$) Gaussian mode on excited fluorophores to relax all those fluorophores aside from those at the very centre and within a distance that is much below the diffraction limit. Then the system reads the fluorescence arising from a *second* pulse following very soon (nanoseconds) after the first and with the same focus, but this time in the zeroth order Gaussian (the one that varies like $e^{-\alpha\,r}$) mode. Now only fluorophores well within a radius that is well below the diffraction limit from the central focal point can contribute to this second reading, and this knowledge lets one infer to within tens of nanometres where the light has come from. Other techniques include modulation of the optical image to achieve the spatial analogue of [syncrhonous downconversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetrodyne) (the same phenomenon that yields Moiré patterns) of the high spatial frequency content of an image down to the spatial frequency range where it can be imaged by conventional, diffraction-limited light microscopy.

Answer (score 0):

This [article in c|net](https://www.cnet.com/news/nanoscope-makes-live-viruses-visible-for-first-time/) discusses a visible-light nanoscope.  However, it's dated 2011, and I haven't found more recent references to the device.  Also, it still wouldn't do what the OP asked, i.e. viewing subatomic particles.  But it was touted as a likely way to view viruses directly, which are generally smaller than the wavelengths of visible light.